# Return more than just false when Auth Login fails

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

Is there a way to return more than just `false` in the `authenticate()` function when `Auth->Login()` fails?

`false` isn't really enough to tell me why Auth failed. Also setting the flash isn't really available when the interface to login doesn't support flash.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what you’re trying to authenticate, but as a general statement authentication systems do not — and should not — give much information about why an authentication attempt fails.

This is because any information could be used to better guess the information needed to authenticate.